# Level Concrete slabs

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete

We bought our house and there is a shed in the yard that was 2 sheds right next to each other. It was recently torn down (not by me) and rebuilt. It's nice to have one single space the only problem is that the slabs were poured differently. One slab slopes from down from right (0") to left (1.5"). I've looked at various self leveling concretes but they say that they are not a wear surface. I believe that this would be too thin to pour with regular concrete on top of this. I've looked at some products such as [this](https://www.menards.com/main/paint/concrete-blacktop-sealers/concrete-repair/rapid-patch-multi-purpose-repair-50-lb/129450/p-1508826492771.htm) but would appreciate everyone's input. Also if I could do it cheaper but in a lasting way that would be great too. [image]

[image]

Comment: I have converted garages that had a similar slope up to 2” at 1 end with nothing at the other, I used a concrete mix close to mortar but in the thicker side I used turkey grit for the aggregate and an addmix to improve the strength as the pour got close to the end I eliminated the grit so it was just a mortar but it worked fine on multiple garage conversions with similar slopes.

Comment: I've patched some spots with leftover thinset tile mortar, which wore better than might be expected for a product not intended to be used as an exposed surface.